# How do I summarize all factors by proportion?

Tags: r

When I run a summary of my dataset, counts are displayed for each variable in my dataset. All of my variables are factors. How do I show percentages instead of counts?

```
> summary(AR)
 Phone_._on_file Credit.Card.Flag Web.Buyer.Flag  flag.spending.last.one.month flag.markdown  
 N: 2054         Mode :logical    Mode :logical   Mode :logical                Mode :logical  
 Y:12436         FALSE:8927       FALSE:13865     FALSE:11433                  FALSE:1847     
                 TRUE :5563       TRUE :625       TRUE :3057                   TRUE :12643    
  Response      
 Mode :logical  
 FALSE:12117    
 TRUE :2373
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own `summary` function.

```
summary_perc <- function(data) {
  lapply(data, function(x) prop.table(table(x)) * 100)  
  #If all columns are logical maybe `sapply` would be helpful.
  #sapply(data, function(x) prop.table(table(x)) * 100)  
}

df <- dplyr::select(mtcars, cyl, am, gear, carb)
summary_perc(df)

#$cyl
#x
#   4    6    8 
#34.4 21.9 43.8 

#$am
#x
#   0    1 
#59.4 40.6 

#$gear
#x
#   3    4    5 
#46.9 37.5 15.6 

#$carb
#x
#    1     2     3     4     6     8 
#21.88 31.25  9.38 31.25  3.12  3.12
```